# How can I assign different control schemes for 2 players using the same keyboard?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, controls, multiplayer

I'm creating a local multiplayer game in which 2 players use the same keyboard to input controls. I have created 2 different control schemes for the players but I'm struggling to find a way to assign each player character a different scheme and how I could check which player is using which scheme e.t.c

Comment: Use KeyCode instead of get axis. And I don’t understand what you mean by “check which player is using which scheme.”

Comment: Adding on to Ken's comment, you can also add additional axes in the input manager. Something along the lines of `Input.GetAxis("P1_horizontal")` and `Input.GetAxis("P2_horizontal")`. Or is your issue determining which instance of your player prefab is player1 and which is player2?

Answer (score 0):

Going to the [Unity GetAxis](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html) you can add another axis form the

> Edit > Project Settings > Input Manager

If you make another 2 axises by the names "*2ndPlayerHorizontal*" , "*2ndPlayerVertical*" and put tags on the players ("*FirstPlayer*", "*SecondPlayer*")

You can use this code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayersMovement: MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 10.0f;
    public float rotationSpeed = 100.0f;

    float translation;
    float rotation;

    void Update()
    {
        if(this.CompareTag("FirstPlayer")
        {
            //1st player
            translation = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed;
            float rotation = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * rotationSpeed;
        }

        if(this.CompareTag("SecondPlayer")
        {
            //2nd player
            translation = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed;
            rotation = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * rotationSpeed;
        }

        translation *= Time.deltaTime;
        rotation *= Time.deltaTime;
        transform.Translate(0, 0, translation);
        transform.Rotate(0, rotation, 0);
    }
}
```